# Excon::Errors::MovedPermanently - When Uploading with Paperclip + Fog to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm trying to upload a File to S3 via Paperclip (2.7.4). I've set up the Model as following:

```
has_attached_file :swatch,
                :styles => {:preview => '50x50>', :display => '50x50>'},
                :storage => :fog,
                :fog_credentials => {
                    :provider => 'AWS',
                    :aws_access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                    :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
                    :region => 'eu-west-1'

                },
                :fog_directory => 'FOG_DIRECTORY',
                :path => '/swatches/:id/:style/:filename'
```

Whenever tough I try to actually upload a File, im getting following error:

> Excon::Errors::MovedPermanently in Spree::Admin::OptionTypesController#update
>   Expected(200) <=> Actual(301 Moved Permanently)

Any Ideas whats going on there?

Comment: are fog directory and region set correct?

Comment: Good Catch - Double Check the Region. Thank yoU!